# Snowflake : Get next Saturday date from today using stored procedure

Tags: javascript, azure, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

I need to get the upcoming saturday based on the date field in table. I need to implement code using snowflake javascript stored procedure. Suggestions appreciated.

When following query is executed using snowflake console, I get result.

`SELECT next_day(TO_DATE(MAX(SALE_DATE)),'Saturday') FROM Sales;`

But when I implement the same using stored procedure it throws error "unexpected Saturday"

Tried to fetch the upcoming Saturday date based on the maximum date in table

```
  var get_cm = "SELECT next_day(TO_DATE(MAX(SALE_DATE)),'Saturday') FROM Sales";
   var get_sql= snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:get_cm);
   var res_dt = get_sql.execute();
   res_dt.next();
   var res = res_dt.getColumnValue(1);
   return res;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adjusted your JS code slightly and it worked for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure NEXT_SATURDAY_TEST()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
   var get_cm = "SELECT next_day(TO_DATE(MAX(SALE_DATE)),'Saturday') FROM Sales;";
   var res_dt = snowflake.execute({sqlText: get_cm});
   res_dt.next();
   var res = res_dt.getColumnValue(1);
   return res;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

This process should work:

1. Get the day of the week of your input date
2. Subtract this from the day of the week for a Saturday (controlled by parameters e.g. WEEK_START)
3. Add this value as a number of days to your input date